# How should abstract inherited files be organized with PSR-4 and composer?

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, psr-4

I wish to create my own composer package, but before doing so, am trying to better understand how it should be organized especially pertaining to abstract classes which are inherited.

Let's say I have some specific items such as:

- SedanCar, SportsCar, etc
- V6Motor, V8Motor, etc
- AutomaticTransmission, FourSpeedTransmission, etc

For each of these items, I have controller classes, model classes, entity classes, and other classes.

I also have abstract classes such as CarController, CarModel, etc, MotorController, MotorModel, etc, etc which the specific classes are extended from using inheritance.

Composition will then be used to inject parts into cars, models into controllers, etc.

How should the directory file structure be organized and what namespaces should be used for this scenario?

Not that I expect the following will be correct, but I will take a stab at it so that you can better understand my current level of understanding on this topic.  I've read posts describing grouping by feature and/or by archetype, and I believe I should first be doing by feature.  The following assumes a NamespaceName of `MyVendorName`, SubNamespaceName of `Car`, and a file path of `/var/www/vendor`. 
 Then maybe I would do:

```
/var/www/vendor/my-vendor-name/src/Car/Controllers/AllMyAbstractControllers.php
/var/www/vendor/my-vendor-name/src/Car/Models/AllMyAbstractModels.php
/var/www/vendor/my-vendor-name/src/Car/Entities/AllMyAbstractEntities.php
/var/www/vendor/my-vendor-name/src/Car/Cars/SportsCar/AllSpecificSportsCar_Controller_Model_Entity_Classes.php
/var/www/vendor/my-vendor-name/src/Car/Cars/SedanCar/AllSpecificSedanCar_Controller_Model_Entity_Classes.php
/var/www/vendor/my-vendor-name/src/Car/Motors/V6Motor/AllSpecificV6Motor_Controller_Model_Entity_Classes.php
/var/www/vendor/my-vendor-name/src/Car/Motors/V8Motor/AllSpecificV8Motor_Controller_Model_Entity_Classes.php
etc, etc...
```

Then, I could have `\MyVendorName\Car\Cars\SportsCar\SportsCarController.php` extend `\MyVendorName\Car\Controllers\CarController.php`.

I am sure the above is wrong, and just provided it as an example.  How should abstract inherited files be organized with PSR-4 and composer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither Composer nor PSR-4 does not recommend anything in this matter - they're focused on technical aspects, so as long you're not using disallowed characters in classes names and files structure matches namespaces structure, they're fine with it.

In fact, there is no one right answer for the question "how should I structure my classes/namespaces". Answer depends on personal preferences and the specifics of the project. If you think that this structure will fit for your project, then use it - you are the person who knows the project the best and you will use it the most, so you are probably the most competent person in this matter.

Comment: Thanks rob006,  Is there any criteria you use to decide how to best organize it?

Comment: @user1032531 Nothing strict. Usually it depends how package will be used: If it will be used as a whole, then separate classes by role (all controllers in one directory, including abstract controller). If only part of package may be used (for example someone needs only sport cars) then separate by domain and include all entities and controllers related to sport cars in one subdirectory.